# Can TF object detection API be used to detect objects that are bounded by another?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

This is a separation of this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47080259/training-with-big-class-imbalance/47092213#47092213)

Can TF object detection API be used to detect two objects where 1 is enclosed / bounded by the other?

Ex. face vs person - face is within the bounds of the person

Answer (score 1):

The answer is Yes.  You essentially don't have to worry about this --- though for various reasons, it may become a more challenging for the algorithm if you have an object enclosing another object that is almost the same size.  Settings like "Face within person" or even "sunglasses within face" should be just fine.

Comment: i was expecting some technical answer so I wasn't sure if this was a good answet.. until i looked at Jonathan's profile and where he works. Good enough for me! ;)

Comment: Jonathan i have a related question... can I bug you with this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47129078/tf-object-detection-api-not-all-classes-are-being-detected-behaving-oddly

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can. You don't have to do any extra things for that. once the detection happen and if it will found one object under some other object. it will give you output which is actually function of multi detection.