# TF Object Detection API - Not ALL classes are being detected & behaving oddly

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

**Setup:**

1. ubuntu 16.04 LTS, 4 vCPU + 30gb ram
2. nvidia K80 GPU w/12gb memory
3. CUDNN 8.0 x64
4. TF version 1.3

Objective: using TF object detection API to detect face, person, pistol, rifle, automatic_rifle

> Steps taken:

**1) Prepare images and bounding boxes**
- face: used WIDER face dataset
- person: used COCO dataset 
- guns: used Image-Net

No. of guns is nowhere near the dataset size for face & person, so I made sure that # of image per each class was similar by limiting the # of face/people images.

90% set to train, and 10% to test

So number of images per class looked like this

train - [see csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bdutSvXrDz9X_L_8twHFTQJJToGQL9mO)

- rifle         401
- revolver      389
- assault_rifle     532
- face          407
- person            389

test - [see csv](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1oKK4FXxcMmrMnSt_4Zfl1WNI7JMBpnPo)

- rifle         45
- revolver      44
- assault_rifle     60
- face          126
- person            44

**2) Generate TF records** ([see code](https://pastebin.com/VGzzZy3m))

```
# see pastebin
```

- Model used: faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco
- Config: Pretty similar to the pet custom detector config, [see code](https://pastebin.com/LZRHG3N5)
- pbtxt file: [see code](https://pastebin.com/sPi9GMAf)

==> Minor Note: There's "nb_epoch" in last line. I noticed this value doesn't exist in other model config files shipped w/TF object detection API (i.e. in folder )

**3) Train** 
Ran over 200k steps.

> Problem

The 5 classes that I trained for do NOT always show up, even on trained images. It seems like either the person OR face is detecting, rarely both.

As a frame of reference, this was the result of the faster_rcnn_inception_resnet_v2_atrous_coco model that comes shipped with TF object detection API. I know it's not apple to apples comparison, but at least you can see the person detection:

[See pictures](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1t3d7a9RJTCvbk8cA5_nFIMLaHGh60F3eL5Q7c-Q1uVw/edit?usp=sharing)

Here's how the custom dataset trained model did:

[See pictures](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l_bSdLcKxdX6LIOUGmfs6ngstpr80nOjIeLw0yv60Qs/edit?usp=sharing)

1) Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

This SO user had a same problem ([TensorFlow Object Detection API Weird Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45029977/tensorflow-object-detection-api-weird-behaviour)), but claimed he solved it by cropping / resizing input image.

Does the training data need to be resized? I don't recall seeing any resizing in the [custom pet detector tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) but i do ask b/c i do see min_ and max_dimension in the config file

Comment: 200k steps ? that sounds like a lot ! did you train from scratch ? I'd recommend you take a pretrained model and only refine it for your classes

Comment: No not from scratch. I used faster rcnn resnet 101 weights

Comment: then I think you train for too long. Why don't you watch your eval measure during the training in tensorboard ? that'll tell you if you model diverges

Comment: I did that b/c I saw a comment in faster_rcnn_resnet101_coco.config that came shipped: "Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will never decay)."

Will try that

Comment: I assumed that it when they train from scratch. In any case, run `eval.py` in parallel to get an idea of how your model is performing. any further discussion is pointless without the learning curves

Answer (score 0):

In your config file you set the num_examples: 8000 is 8000, set that number to how many test images you are tacking. for example your are taking 200 images in test folder, then "num_examples:200: